# Using Desire2Learn/Valence with SSO

Tags: desire2learn

From the Valance documentation it looks like the user is always required to enter credentials at the D2L site.  Is there a way for Valence to be used, without the user re-entering credentials, when a user is already authenticated by the originating webapplication?  Is some type of SSO available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In the typical configuration for SSO between a web app and the Learning Suite the same authentication service is used (either the Learning Suite itself, or a separate authentication service , or possibly the webapp that is calling in is also acting as an authenticator in the case of a portal).  If any of these scenarios apply, SSO will work as follows:

Authentication is done within the browser so if the user is authenticated already and goes to the authentication service it will already have the session cookies associated with the authentications service. Therefore when the auth step is triggered it will be pass through -- meaning the user is not prompted for credentials (on the first use the user will be prompted to allow access to this app).

Additionally note that Valence APIs do not use session tokens that are subject to hijacking and instead uses ids and keys (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/auth.html) that are used to perform signatures. As a result those keys are long lived. Apps do not need to reauthenticate the user to the LMS if they still have keys from a previous execution of the app (these keys will be reset in certain circumstances so callers must be prepared to respond to a reset key). As a result you would not typically reauthenticate a user to the Learning Suite every time the user has a session.

(if the above does not apply other SSO scenarios may possible)

Comment: This is the part that's not clear to me from the docs "if the user is authenticated already and goes to the authentication service it will already have the session cookies associated with the authentications service".  Say the webapp is a portal so the user will have session cookies for the portal, but not the LMS.  How are the session cookies for the LMS generated without the user presenting credentials again?  The diagrams on the docs all reference sending the user to some form of https://server.com/d2l/api/token.. .